# How to remove random rows from pandas dataframe based on column entry?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have a dataset of ~3700 rows and need to remove 1628 of those rows based on the column. The dataset looks like this:

```
compliance  day0  day1  day2  day3  day4
True        1     3     9     8     8
False       7     4     8     3     2
True        4     5     0     3     5
True        5     3     9     6     2
```

for 1068 rows I want to remove the entire row if compliance=true.

The thing is, I want to do this randomly; I don't want to remove the first 1063 rows. I tried this:

```
for z in range(1629):
    rand = random.randint(0,(3783-z)) #subtract z since dataframe shape is shrinking
    if str(data.iloc[rand,1]) == 'True':
        data = data.drop(balanced_dataset.index[rand])
```

But I'm getting the following error, after it removes a few rows:

```
 'labels [2359] not contained in axis'
```

I also tried this:

```
data.drop(data("adherence.str.startswith('T').values").sample(frac=.4).index)
```

frac is arbitrarily  picked for now, I just wanted it to work. I got the following error:

```
'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I've also figured out that it works until the random number gives the same number twice

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973423/typeerror-dataframe-object-is-not-callable simalar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:
you generate a list of the indices from which you want to remove element (in your case `Compliance==True`). Then you choose randomly (without replacement) from that list as many elements as you would like removed.
Then you remove them from the DataFrame

```
to_remove = np.random.choice(data[data['Compliance']==True].index,size=1068,replace=False)
data.drop(to_remove)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `sample` with `drop`:

```
n = 1068
# Do this first if you haven't already.
# df.compliance = df.compliance.map(pd.eval)
df_dropped = df.drop(df[df.compliance].sample(n=n).index)
```

For this to work, `n` will need to be strictly smaller than the filtered DataFrame.

---

Example dropping two rows randomly.

```
df.drop(df[df.compliance].sample(n=2).index)

   compliance  day0  day1  day2  day3  day4
1       False     7     4     8     3     2
3        True     5     3     9     6     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`df_dropped = df.drop(df.loc[df.compliance, :]).sample(n=fraction).index)`